# How to download and install updates from windows store using c++ windows sdk api?

Tags: windows, c++-cx

I am trying to write the code which check is an update is available in windows store and download it from there. I am working on c++, so I want to use code from this page https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates and particularly method

> public async Task DownloadAndInstallAllUpdatesAsync()

which is described there, but I failed to convert it to C++. I have done something like this:

```
.h
    Windows::Services::Store::StoreContext^ context = nullptr;
    Concurrency::task<Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<Windows::Services::Store::StorePackageUpdate ^> ^> updatesTask;
    void DownloadAndInstallAllUpdatesAsync();



.cpp
void myApp::DownloadAndInstallAllUpdatesAsync()
{
    if (context == nullptr)
        context = StoreContext::GetDefault();

    // Get the updates that are available.
    updatesTask = create_task(context->GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync());

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    updatesTask.then([this](IVectorView<StorePackageUpdate^>^ const &update) {
        if (update->Size > 0) {

            // Download and install the updates.
            IAsyncOperationWithProgress<StorePackageUpdateResult^, StorePackageUpdateStatus>^ downloadOperation =
                context->RequestDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync(update);
        }
    });
}
```

But I have two troubles with this code:

- Without running **sleep** for two seconds for thread I do not always receive answer from async calling **context->GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync();**
- After calling **context->RequestDownloadAndInstallStorePackageUpdatesAsync(update);** I got a popup with a question whether I want to download update or I want to reject this operation, and no matter which answer I choose my application hanging...

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:c++-winrt], but the code is using [tag:c++-cx]. Please update the tags to reflect what you are looking for. If indeed you want to be using C++/CX, you're best advised dropping the [tag:c++] tag, too. C++/CX isn't C++ (unlike C++/WinRT).

Comment: I have updated tags. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question? I'm finding myself in the same situation.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, I gave up on this one. Instead we are going with external web socket end point, so to check the last released version...

Comment: @RomanYurkovskiy Could you explain a bit how you did with the external web socket endpoint to check the latest version?